# php loop array assignment

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like the one below. I would like to iterate over a loop and assign to 3 different variables the corresponding strings. so for instance:

**Output**:

```
$mike = 'foo - ';
$john = 'bar foo foo - bar foo foo - bar foo bar - '
$bob =  'bar foo bar bar foo - bar foo - '
```

What would be a short(est) way of doing this? thanks

**Initial array**

```
Array
(
    [mike] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo -
        )
    [john] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar foo foo - 
            [1] => bar foo foo - 
            [2] => bar foo bar - 
        )
    [bob] => Array
        (
            [0] => bar foo bar - 
            [1] => bar foo - 
            [2] => bar foo - 
        )
)
```

Comment: the question is: what is the question ..!!??

Comment: basically create 3 vars ($mike, $john, $bob) and assign the corresponding elements to each var. I don't want to do `$john = $array['john'][0].$array['john'][1].$array['john'][2]...` in order to have all elements appended to `$john` in this case

Comment: @Sigtran - the question is "will you write my code for me"

Answer (score 5):

This is a case for [variables variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
   $$key = implode($values);
}
```

However, you may not really need them. I would use an array instead:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $values) {
   $result[$key] = implode($values);
}
```

So you'd get:

```
Array
(
    [mike] => foo -
    [john] => bar foo foo - bar foo foo - bar foo bar - 
    [bob] => bar foo bar - bar foo - bar foo - 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use [extract()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) and [implode()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$a = array( 'mike'  => array('foo -'),
            'john'  => array('bar foo foo - ',
                             'bar foo foo - ',
                             'bar foo bar - '
                            ),
            'bob'   => array('bar foo bar - ',
                             'bar foo - ',
                             'bar foo - '
                            )
          );

foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $a[$k] = implode(' ',$v);
}
extract($a);

var_dump($mike);
var_dump($john);
var_dump($bob);
```